# Squad selection in Starcraft

Tags: starcraft

I only know how to assign 10 squads to control groups using numbers 0 through 9, but I need more.

How can I assign more than ten squads to control groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to assign more than 10 control groups in Starcraft.